# How to get absolute url in JSF?

Tags: java, jsf, javabeans

I am trying to write a navigation for my web app in JSF.

I have this, so far:

```
<ul>
<ui:repeat value="#{pageBean.getPages()}" var="page">
   <li class="#{(pageContext.request.requestURI.endsWith(page.url)) ? 'current_page_item' : '' }">
       <a href="#{pageContext.servletContext.getRealPath(page.url)}">#{page.name}</a>
   </li>
</ui:repeat>
</ul>
```

But anchor's href attribute is always empty. Also I am not sure if `pageContext.request.requestURI.endsWith(page.url)` works correctly - I guess not, because no page has current_page_item class.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `getRealPath()` indeed doesn't do what you think it does. Read its [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getRealPath%28java.lang.String%29).

But this approach is unnecessarily overcomplicated. You don't need to generate an absolute path yourself if you use the JSF `<h:link>` component in combination with a list of view IDs. The `<h:link>` will automatically prepend the right context path, if any.

```html
<ul>
    <ui:repeat value="#{pageBean.pages}" var="page">
        <li class="#{view.viewId == page.viewId ? 'current_page_item' : ''}">
            <h:link value="#{page.name}" outcome="#{page.viewId}" />
        </li>
    </ui:repeat>
</ul>
```

The view ID is exactly the page identifier which JSF uses under its covers to locate views and handle navigation. The view ID is the webcontent-relative path to the view file, such as `/foo/index.xhtml`.

Note that the `#{view}` in the above example is an [implicit EL variable](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#ImplicitELObjects) pointing to the current `UIViewRoot`, so you don't need to create/prepare it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

This is a misunderstanding of what [`getRealPath`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getRealPath%28java.lang.String%29) does. This will translate a URL of the form `http://<host>:<port>/<contextPath>/index.html` to something like `C:\foo\bar\index.html`. Remote systems have no use for this information. The method returns null for resources that don't correspond to files. The method is mostly useless and applications should avoid using it.